# Copy filtered range to new workbook (ignore no results)

Tags: excel, vba, filter

What I'm trying to do is copy the filtered range (minus the headers), but when the filtered range returns no results, I want it to ignore.

It seems to be working fine when there is data in the filtered range, however I am getting the following overflow error when the filtered range returns no results:

[image]

When debugging, it highlighted the following code:

```
If Worksheets("Cash Data (XXX)").Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
```

Here is my code in it entirety:

```
'   Filter 250000+ items (XXX)

    With Workbooks("MI Dashboard.xlsm").Worksheets("Cash Data (XXX)").Range("A1")

        .AutoFilter field:=15, Criteria1:="<>Inactive", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>Tax"
        .AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:=">250000"

    End With

'   Copy to risk items workbook

    Workbooks("MI Dashboard.xlsm").Sheets("Cash Data (XXX)").Activate
    Dim N4 As Long
         N4 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    If Worksheets("Cash Data (XXX)").Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then

    Worksheets("Cash Data (XXX)").Range("A2:I" & N4).Copy _
    Destination:=Workbooks("Temp.xlsx").Sheets("Cash").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    Worksheets("Cash Data (XXX)").Range("J2:T" & N4).Copy _
    Destination:=Workbooks("Temp.xlsx").Sheets("Cash").Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1)

    Else

    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually when there are no results, your `End(xlUp)` is going to the last row and which is giving you a Overflow error

**Change the Line:**

```
Worksheets("Cash Data (XXX)").Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
```

**with :**

```
Worksheets("Cash Data (XXX)").Range("A1:A" & N4).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I have tried it and I am still getting the overflow error. It is now correctly counting the correct range, which is 1 (the header).

Comment: If Worksheets("Cash Data (XXX)").Range("A1:A" & N4).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then

Comment: @Jason ... I son't see any scope for that error now. Can you share the Workbook, I ll take a look at the code for you.

Comment: i am unable to share the workbook, as it has sensitive data in it. Are you happy to have a blank version with just the code?

Comment: Also, you can try one more thing, define all your integers to `Double` ... Basically change all `Dim ///// As Integer` to `Dim //// As Double`

Comment: I've resolved this issue. I took SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) out of the code. For some reason it kept returning 12 as the value when hovering over it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Mikku's amended code, I have resolved the overflow error by taking out `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` from the code.

**Mikku's code:**

```
IF Worksheets("Cash Data (XXX)").Range("A1:A" & N4).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
```

**Corrective code:**

```
If Worksheets("Cash Data (XXX)").Range("A1:A" & N4).Rows.Count > 1 Then
```